# CMFCListCtrl SetFont

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

When setting the font in CMFCListCtrl is it possible to only set the font in the column/row items itself? I would like the headerctrl to keep the default font. By setting the font for the control it sets the font for both the list and header.

Comment: After setting the list font, you can manually restore the original font on the header.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. Much easier than subclassing or overriding the control. Just 2 additional lines to get pointer to header and set the font back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellFont()` to do that.

Comment: The CMFCListCtrl is embedded in the main view and to keep it simple it is not an ownerdraw control. I have set the font for the entire control then set the font for the controls header using getheaderctrl back to the views default font and that does seem to work. Is there an easier way of doing this or should I just do it this way since the control is not ownerdrawn?

Comment: I don't see any difficulties deriving from CMFCListCtrl and overriding OnGetCellFont(). There is no other way of doing it.